# Conditional expected value

Tags: probability

Could someone help me out proving this proposition?

Let X and Y be two random variables defined in the same probability space taking values in $\mathbb{N}$ . Let $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be any function and suppose that $h:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a bijective function. Then

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ g(X) | h(Y)\right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ g(X) | Y\right] $$

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I preassume that $\mathbb N$ is equipped with $\sigma$-algebra $\wp(\mathbb N)$ so that every function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is measurable.

Random variable $h(Y)$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$.

If $\ell$ denotes the inverse of $h$ (which exists because $h$ is bijective) then $Y=\ell(h(Y))$ showing that conversely random variable $Y$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $h(Y)$.

These two facts show that $Y$ and $h(Y)$ generate the same $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ so that: $$\mathbb E[Z\mid Y]=\mathbb E[Z\mid\mathcal A]=\mathbb E[Z\mid h(Y)]$$ for any integrable random variable $Z$.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the edit. I overlooked that $g$ was in use also.

Comment: You are welcome. (Nice answer, quite to the point.)